# Why we care only about $\Pi_1$ parameters in axiom schemes?

Tags: logic, notation, set-theory, peano-axioms

There is exist tradition to formulate axiom schemes such as induction, comprehension or replacment in a way like "for each formula $\phi(y,\overline{x})$ with free variables $y$ and $\overline{x}=x_1,...,x_n$ we have $\forall \overline{x} ( \text{text of axiom scheme which include } \phi(y,\overline x))$". To not be vague, let take as archetypical example comprehension scheme for second order arithmetics from [ncatlab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/second-order+arithmetic#secondorder_axioms).

> $ \forall \overline m \forall \overline X \exists Z \forall n (n \in Z \leftrightarrow \phi(n,\overline m, \overline X))$

I choose that example because I don't know it is equivalent to axiom without parameters or not, whenever equivalence to $ZFC$ or first order $PA$ to versions without parameters is classical result.  I understand that apriori allowing parameters could increase expressible power of our system, but I don't understand why we not allowing not only $\Pi_1$ parameters but parameters of all type like, for example, next $\Sigma_3$ axiom scheme

> $\exists \overline m_1 \exists \overline X_1 \forall \overline m_2 \forall \overline X_2 \exists \overline m_3 \exists \overline X_3 \exists Z \forall n (n \in Z \leftrightarrow \phi(n,\overline m_1, \overline X_1, \overline m_2, \overline X_2, \overline m_3, \overline X_3))$

it seems for me like it could increase our expressible power a lot, so, why it is not traditional?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You are right it was mistyping. I am fix it

Comment: What does it mean for a parameter to be $\Pi_1$?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what kind of "flexibility" are you thinking about... Consider the simple case $∀m∃Z∀n(n∈Z ↔ ϕ(n,m))$; the schema means that, for fixed $\phi$, we have a "collections" of sets $Z_m$, one for each value of the parameter $m$.

Comment: If we instead use $∃$ what we get is $∃m∃Z∀n(n∈Z ↔ ϕ(n,m))$ that means that - for the specific value of $m$ that satisfies the formula - we have a single set $Z$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It means that it have form $\forall \text{param} (\text{axiom scheme})$ as analogy to arithmetical hierarchy of formulas.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay, what about $\forall m_3 \exists m_2 \forall m_1$?

Comment: But these give you partial functions, or sets, or whatever, and no control over them. These schemata are meant to be a big sword that can be swung and chop off all the heads of the hydra at once. Introducing dependent parameters is just... Wrong. Also, I suspect this can be coded back into a $\Pi_1$ form using the fact ordered pairs are just sets (or coded by integers in the PA case).

Comment: @AsafKaragila In fact I am not have good intuition about why we introduce parameters in axiom schemes at all, maybe you could write about it and publish it as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I will have time until tomorrow evening to write a long answer to anything.